# Do I need to remove a 2 inch screw I dropped down the toilet waste pipe?

Tags: toilet, blockage

I replaced my bathroom floor and installed a new toilet. By accident I dropped a 2 inch brass screw down the flange waste pipe. Before I caulk everything up, I thought I’d check to see if it would be OK (would it wash down_ or should I attempt to remove it? If so, how would I do this - it seemed to have slid a number of feet down past a join and since it is brass, I can’t use a magnet to try to extract it. Would it wash down with waste or cause a blockage later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will wash down with the waste. The 2" screw in a 3 or 4" pipe should be of no concern....